# "No such file or directory:" Issue with ADALiOS versions 2.2.5 and 2.2.6

Tags: ios, azure, adal

I am using Windows Azure Active Directory (ADAL library 2.2.4) authentication mechanism in my iOS applications. Recently I have received one email from Microsoft team sys that

> "All ADAL .iOS versions 2.2.4 and lower prevent interactive login on
>   iOS10, that means users will be locked out of their account when their
>   current sign-in expires between 14 – 90 days. If a user is already
>   signed in to your application it will continue to work temporarily,
>   but the next time they need to sign in again they will experience this
>   issue."

Then I tried to update with latest ADAL versions 2.2.5 and 2.2.6 from the link https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/releases but these versions are not compiling successfully. Always facing error `(null): No such file or directory: '/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-aeiapfbshlzesxhfptwxpoahxjss/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libADALiOS.a'`

The "libADALiOS.a" library file dose not copy into above location.
[image]

Please help me on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been fixed recently. But release with such a fix will be coming later.

A possible mitigation is to link to libADAL-core.a instead of libADALiOS.a.

Check this: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/issues/756

Comment: Thank you. You saved my time. libADALiOS.a got generated after adding a dummy ADAL.m into the project.

Comment: If I remove/change ADAL folder location after drag & drop or add ADAL.xcodeproj into main project, then the ADAL.xcodeproj and associated files are not available and all are showing in red color. Is there any way to keep files and subproject even remove/change the subproject location?